# Folder Monitoring with Batch File

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory, monitoring

I want to monitor my folder if new file added or not. Then If added I would like to execute some files. But I don't want to use third party app.

I have some ideas but I don't know how to do that.

This is my folder; D:\MonitoringFolder

So every hour batch file will check the files inside of it and writes them into a txt.

```
dir /b "D:\MonitoringFolder" > old.txt
```

Old.txt is --> string 1 , string 2, string 3

After one hour, batch file will check it later and writes again into another txt.

```
dir /b "D:\MonitoringFolder" > new.txt
```

New.txt is --> string 1, string 2, string 3, string 5

Then it will compare new.txt and old.txt. So string 5 added recently. It will prompt a window and says "String 5" added!. Or new file added (removed).

I want to do that If someone could show me a way to do this I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already dumping the output every hour, just execute this command from the prompt:

```
fc /u old.txt new.txt
```

It will tell you, if any, which differences exist between the two files.

Answer (score 1):

Script MONITOR.cmd scheduled to run every now and then:

```
IF EXIST NEW.TXT DEL NEW.TXT
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%* IN ('DIR /S /B /ON "D:\MonitoringFolder"') DO ECHO "%%*">>NEW.TXT
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%* IN (NEW.TXT) DO (FIND %%* OLD.TXT >NUL || START CMD /K INSERTED.cmd %%*)
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%* IN (OLD.TXT) DO (FIND %%* NEW.TXT >NUL || START CMD /K  DELETED.cmd %%*)
DEL OLD.TXT
REN NEW.TXT OLD.TXT
```

Script INSERTED.cmd will create new window prompting for action on appearing of a new file:

```
ECHO Inserted new file %1
DIR %1
PAUSE & EXIT
```

Script DELETED.cmd will create new window prompting for action on disappearing of an old file:

```
ECHO Deleted file %1
PAUSE & EXIT
```

Subfolders are monitored, too. It worked for me even with spaces and accented characters in filename.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're going to write batch scripts (for scanning folder and compare results) and schedule them with a scheduler like cron (Linux) or windows task scheduler every hours for e periodical checking. Some documents here : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569 , http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800

Comment: Problem is writing that script, I can handle the tasks but comparing files and prompting a message is a problem for me

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL disableDelayedExpansion
SET "SaveFile=Save.File"
IF NOT EXIST "%SaveFile%" GOTO:cont
DIR /b /a-d | FINDSTR /vg:"%SaveFile%">nul||EXIT /b
ECHO(execute some programs here
:cont
>"%SaveFile%" DIR /b /a-d
```

Comment: It's not updating after removing a file :/ And I can't check another folder except where the bat file located.

Comment: No, this wasn't the question. Btw. this might fail, if you use local characters ex. `äàáâç`

Comment: But question is monitoring a folder, I just gave an example. It wouldn't be a problem those local characters for me. And also it's not checking the subfolders :/

Comment: This was not requested. But my code is freeware- patches welcome  :)

Comment: If you can patch it I would be appreciate that at least It can check subfolders and specified folder not the bat file located

Comment: `findstr` can not work with path names, so the subfolder story doesn't work :/