# Folder Monitoring/Batch file execution

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, file-watcher

I am attempting to create a script that will monitor a folder (a Dropbox folder).

When I need to shutdown my PC, I will just drop a file into the Dropbox folder. The script will see the new file, run a shutdown batch file, and delete the file in the Dropbox folder.

Please help me implement this.

To summarize:

- Check folder for new files.
- If there is one, run `shutdown.bat`.
- Delete the file in the folder.

Comment: Can you post the batch file that you have tired creating? As many users will point out, SO isn't a code writing service

Comment: In terms of the file monitoring script I have nothing all I have is the shutdown file and an attempt I had before at trying to shutdown the computers over LAN but I kept getting a permissions error I was not able ti rectify.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to drop a file into a dropbox folder and that will trigger this batch file to remove that file, and call a shutdown batch file.

```
@echo off
cls

rem set these first before running the script
set pathtoDBfile=
set sdBatfile=

rem check if the file in the dropbox folder exists
if exist %pathtoDBfile% (
    del /q %pathtoDBfile%
    call:%sdBatfile%
}
```

You should read up on running a batch file in the background to monitor the folder. May not be exactly what you want, but this is the best solution I could come up with.

These links should help you out more with your problem:

[Folder Monitoring with Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961763/folder-monitoring-with-batch-file)

[Windows XP or later Windows: How can I run a batch file in the background with no window displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298562/windows-xp-or-later-windows-how-can-i-run-a-batch-file-in-the-background-with-n)